# SELECT Statement Returns Rows Outside DATETIME

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement in SQL Server that is pulling more rows than it should and I can not figure out why.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(50), [EventStamp], 120)
FROM 
    A2ALMDB.dbo.v_AlarmHistory
WHERE 
    EventStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-31 00:00' AND '2018-09-01 00:00'
    AND Area = 'Additives_CLX' OR Area = 'Mixer_CTRLX'
ORDER BY 
    EventStamp DESC
```

This statement will return ~250000 rows from my database digging up dates outside the dates I want while:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(50), [EventStamp], 120)
FROM 
    A2ALMDB.dbo.v_AlarmHistory
WHERE 
    EventStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-31 00:00' AND '2018-09-01 00:00'
    AND Area = 'Additives_CLX' 
ORDER BY 
    EventStamp DESC
```

is working correctly; what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Might also want to take a peek at this. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your first query with logic like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), [EventStamp], 120)
FROM A2ALMDB.dbo.v_AlarmHistory
WHERE EventStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-31 00:00' AND '2018-09-01 00:00' AND
      Area IN ('Additives_CLX', 'Mixer_CTRLX')
ORDER BY EventStamp DESC;
```

This is probably what you intend.  Your query is parsed as:

```
WHERE (EventStamp BETWEEN '2018-08-31' AND '2018-09-01' AND Area = 'Additives_CLX') OR
      Area = 'Mixer_CTRLX'
```

So the date condition is only applied to `'Additives_CLX'`, not to both values.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly, I wasn't aware of the IN statement. I guess I should be using this in all case where I use multiple OR statements?

Comment: @chumnend Mostly you need to be aware that OR has lower precedence than AND in the same way multiplication and addition have an "order of operations".

Comment: @chumnend . . . When you can use `IN`, use it.  When you have `AND` and `OR`, I would recommend that you use parentheses to be sure the expression is evaluated as you intend.